# Undeploy of a pod from kubernates cluster dashboard

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want to undeploy pod/redeploy for previous image - meaning reverting of code. This should happen from kubernates dashboard. Like there is option to delete deployment in cluster dashboard .. similarly is there a way to undeploy or redeploy to previous image tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently roll back from the dashboard, no. Actually there is an open feature request asking for it - https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/2889

Rolling back a deployment from the command-line is possible (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-back-a-deployment) or you could switch the image referenced by your deployment. But rollback is not currently a feature of the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes Dashboard v1.8.1 and later, go to **Workload->Deployment** section, and when you press triple dot button to the left of any deployment, there is the "**View/edit YAML**" option right after "**Scale**" and "**Delete**" options.

When you select that option, YAML editor opens, and you can change the image property (e.g., set the previous one) and update the deployment. Changes are applied instantly.